# Add COUNT column in SQL output

Tags: sql

I have a 10k row data set where a column, "mode", has either a '0' or '1' integer value. I am attempting to write a query that simply counts the number of '0' and '1' values.

These work but don't tell the whole story:

```sql
SELECT mode
    FROM unpopular_songs
    GROUP BY mode;
```

This shows the mode column with just two rows (0 and 1).

```sql
SELECT 
    COUNT(mode) AS minor
    FROM unpopular_songs
    WHERE mode = '0';
```

This shows one column labeled as "MINOR", with one row with a count as 3905. So, this tells part of the story. However, I need another column "MAJOR" that shows the count of values of '1'.

This was my best shot at getting the output I wanted, but it's throwing an error:

```sql
SELECT 
    COUNT(mode = '0') AS minor
    COUNT(mode = '1') AS major
    FROM unpopular_songs;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need some grouping:

```
SELECT COUNT(1), mode
  FROM unpopular_songs 
 GROUP BY mode;
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you. Although I don't understand how **COUNT(1)** functions in this scenario. I tried it with **COUNT(0)** and it provided the same output. Can you explain why?

Comment: Actually it wouldn't matter or at least in oracle it doesn't matter, any number would do and count(*) should return the same result also. As long as you use the group by and make no restrictions in the where clause, it will work and count all records. You can mark as accepted if you think it answers your question.

Comment: count(x) counts the rows where x is not null. So if you put in a literal that is not null it doesn't really matter what you put in.

Comment: Common practice is to do `count(*)`. (As said, you can use any other constant expression - if you want to confuse your co-workers.)